# Search for file - Java - need a upgrade

Tags: java

I need to make two little additions to this Java program.

1. I need to make it show a complete path when I try to search for a file. At this moment it only shows me `E:\books\comics\` when I search for xmen.txt. I'm trying to make it show `E:\books\comics\xmen.txt` as the result.
2. I need to make it show me a NO results are found if there are no files named like that when searched.

Also, I'm not trained with Java and this program is for a paperwork assignment on a topic about "searching possibilities". I'm trying to make it cool by adding object-oriented programming into the subject.

```
class FindFile
{
    public void findFile(String name, File file)
    {
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        if(list!=null)
        for (File fil : list)
        {
            if (fil.isDirectory())
            {
                findFile(name,fil);
            }
            else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fil.getName()))
            {
                System.out.println(fil.getParentFile());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write the file you are trying to find:" );
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Write the directory where you want to search for the file");
        String directory = scan.next();
        System.out.println("File was found in: ");
        ff.findFile(name,new File(directory));
    }
}
```

Comment: State of the art [searching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html). Only if youre not stuck with basics.

Comment: There is no real OOP here, just a class and some recursion. Not that it's really an OOP-style problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, this will need some work though:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class FindFile 
{
    public String findFile(String name,File file) throws IOException
    {
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        if (list != null)
        {
            for (File fil : list)
            {
                if (fil.isDirectory())
                {
                    return findFile(name,fil);
                }
                else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fil.getName()))
                {
                    return fil.getCanonicalPath();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write the file you are trying to find:" );
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Write the directory where you want to search for the file");
        String directory = scan.next();
        String foundFile = ff.findFile(name,new File(directory));
        if (foundFile != null)
        {
            System.out.println("File was found in: " + foundFile);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if `list` is not `null` too.

Comment: Fixed the above, plus added a `throws IOException` to the `main` method.